# Manage SQL Server stored procedures in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

It is well known that perfomance wise, it is recommended to use SQL Server stored procedures instead of inline code. However, I still use inline SQL queries in Visual Studio for various reasons:

- The queries can be neatly organized in separate text files (`.sql`) and in a folder structure.
- The files are part of the Visual Studio solution and thus submitted to source control.
- Changes to SQL queries can be published together with the applications (using WebDeploy for ASP.NET apps or ClickOnce for Windows apps).
- There is no need to synchronize changes to the SQL queries and publishing new versions of applications.
- It enables me to work on the SQL queries even when I am offline (or without access to that particular SQL Server).

I am not quite ready to give up these advantages but still, I am aware that I am sacrificing performance.

Is there a way to get the best of both worlds?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Chris

Comment: You can have a SQL Project in Visual Studio. That at least brings them under source control and allows you to organize them and work on them offline.

Comment: you can store stored procedure definitions as text files (on my last project, we did it regularly, storing them as .sqlp for procedures, .sqlf for functions and .sqlv for views, just so we'd know what was what). In my new job we use SQL Database Projects in Visual Studio, which do all that and are a bit more convenient because you can directly sync it with a database, so you can write changes in Visual Studio and then publish them like you would publish an application, and you can make it keep a record of the scripts it ran during the publish operation, so you've got an audit trail.

Comment: @ADyson just so the file types are always recognized, I name mine like this usp_{procName}.sql (for stored procedure) or uf_{functionName}.sql, or uv_{viewName}.sql. That way you know the type of file that it is, and you can leave the .sql extension so it's "recognized"

Comment: @ganders Good point. But they'd written (10 years before my time) a completely custom little script which would read the files from a pre-defined folder structure, look at the file extension to know how to deal with it, and then deploy it. It could do a whole pre-patch, code update, post-patch deployment run out the folder structure with one click. So the issue of extension recognition wasn't really a problem, as the tool was expecting them. And I just set up my editors to associate the extensions as being SQL files.

Comment: The primary reason to use stored procedures is *not* performance. As noted by @Milney most of the performance advantages can be realized with parametized queries.  The real reasons to use stored procedures are better management, better DB re-use and integrity, and most of all better ***security***.

Comment: It is a **well-known, well-documented MYTH** that stored procedures would be **any faster** than a comparable, *properly parametrized* inline T-SQL query. This is simply **not the case!** Stop spreading that myth ......

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. Particularly those about the performance myth, since that is indeed news to me. My current queries are indeed properly parametrized queries, and I pass the parameters with their types to avoid type sniffing.
Also thanks for the tips about the SQL project type -  I feel kind of stupid for not finding out about those myself. I tried it, but it does not seem to add much to my current method - apart from having tables, views and functions also in my source-controlled VS project, which is currently not the case.

Comment: But finally, since it does not seem to improve the performance of my queries, and it will be a lot of effort to migrate the existing queries, I will leave the current project as it is. I'll keep the SQL project type in mind for future projects. I will mark Milney's answer, because it seems to be a proper summary of all your helpful comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literally every single one of your points can be provided by Stored Procedures too... Not only could you just have a .sql file with the CREATE or ALTER command for the stored procedure in the exact same way you manage it now, but you could go a step further and use a SQL Database Project type to deploy them in a better manner...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee70aty(v=vs.140).aspx

But I will note that stored procedures are not automatically better for performance... If you read this is probably refered to the fact that they are easier to parameterize, so the plans can be resued. Using proper Parameterized queries you will have the same benefits, so I think the basic premise of your question is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

*I still use inline SQL queries in Visual Studio ...*

But how? Context is important here. VS is just a tool. If you use inline queries in your app, then you have a potential security risk if you are not careful about how you implement them (re: sql injection). In addition, the use of inline queries requires the appropriate permissions to database objects - another security risk. And this approach creates a dependency between your code and the schema - which is minimized by using procedures.

Comment: He said he stores them in .sql files, so I think he means 'inline' in that they are text not that he actually hard codes them into his C# code files... So I don't think your comments are relevant here (Although they are very sensible in general!)

Comment: Indeed, they are not really inline. They are parametrized queries stored in separate .sql files. I then "import" these SQL files into a resource file, enabling me to call them like 'var command = new SqlCommand(SqlQueries.searchTheseObjects)' and adding typed (to parameter sniffing) parameters, thus preventing SQL injection.

Comment: (to *avoid* parameter sniffing)